Express.Multer.File to ReadStream
I want to upload my video but the wrapper for Bunny.Net (https://github.com/dan-online/bunnycdn-stream/tree/main/src) in createAndUploadVideo method requires the ReadStream type while Express.Multer.File gave me only buffer and stream properties. How to convert any of them to ReadStream? There is createReadStream metho in fs library but I don't have a path to put there since the file is not uploaded yet.
  @ApiUpload('', { useAuthGuard: false, description: 'Upload file - max 25mb', type: OutputFileDto })
  async create(@User() user: UserEntity, @UploadedFile() uploadedFile: Express.Multer.File) {
    return this._fileService.create(user, uploadedFile);
  }

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  const configService: ConfigService<IConfiguration> = app.get(ConfigService);

  // generate REST API documentation
  const documentation = new DocumentBuilder().setTitle('API documentation').setVersion('1.0');
  documentation.addBearerAuth();
  SwaggerModule.setup(
    '',
    app,
    SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, documentation.build(), {
      extraModels: [],
    }),
  );

  // interceptors
  app.useGlobalInterceptors(new LoggerInterceptor());

  // validate DTOs
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({ whitelist: true, transform: true }));

  // handle unique entities error from database
  const { httpAdapter } = app.get(HttpAdapterHost);
  app.useGlobalFilters(new QueryErrorFilter(httpAdapter));

  // enable cors
  app.enableCors();

  // raw body
  app.use(
    json({
      limit: '1mb',
      verify: (req: IncomingMessage, res: ServerResponse, buf: Buffer, encoding: BufferEncoding) => {
        if (buf && buf.length) {
          req['rawBody'] = buf.toString(encoding || 'utf8');
        }
      },
    }),
  );

  // security
  app.use(helmet());

  app.use(
    rateLimit({
      windowMs: 900000,
      max: 50099,
      message: { status: 429, message: 'Too many requests, please try again later.' },
    }),
  );

  await app.listen(configService.get('basic.port', { infer: true }));
}

bootstrap();

In my create method I have
 async create(user: UserEntity, uploadedFile: Express.Multer.File) {
    let url: string = '';
    let storageKey: string = '';
    let length: number | undefined;
    console.log(uploadedFile);
    if (['video/mp4'].includes(uploadedFile.mimetype)) {
      const stream = new BunnyCdnStream({
        videoLibrary: '...',
        apiKey: '...',
      });

      const readable = Readable.from(uploadedFile.buffer);
      console.log(readable);
      const video = await stream.createAndUploadVideo(readable, { title: '' });

    } else {
      storageKey = `files/${new Date().getTime()}-${slugify(uploadedFile.originalname)}`;
      url = await this._uploadService.save(storageKey, uploadedFile.buffer, uploadedFile.mimetype);
    }

    if (!url) {
      throw new BadRequestException(ErrorMessages.FILE_UPLOAD_FAILED);
    }

    return this._fileRepository.save(
      new FileEntity({
        originalname: uploadedFile.originalname,
        mimetype: uploadedFile.mimetype,
        size: uploadedFile.size,
        url,
        storageKey,
        user,
        length,
      }),
    );
  }


you can use Readable.from

You can use Readable.from method from node:stream to convert buffer into readable stream
const { Readable } = require("node:stream");

/* import { Readable } from 'node:stream'; */ if ESM

/** In your controller **/

app.post('/path', (req,res) => {

    const Readable = Readable.from(req.file.buffer);

    // Logic to pass the readable to createAndUploadVideo

})


Hi, I dont get how to apply it in my case. I added how my Controller method looks like and how my app is built. Could you please point wheere should I apply your code?

I added my create method as well

It is working or not? code seems good

No it does not work :(
